# Can I add more fields to the pre-filled template in actions-on-google console?

Tags: actions-on-google

If I am going to use a template to create a trivia using prefilled [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3FHJgQlofapqcJDgfeW3umOlQHFQX-BV9gQA1tB1sE/copy) Can I edit the structure to add more Follow-ups? The structure is

```
Question    Correct Answer  Incorrect Answer 1  Incorrect Answer 2  Follow Up
```

Can I make it

```
Question    Correct Answer  Incorrect Answer 1  Incorrect Answer 2  Follow Up Follow Up Follow Up
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a single follow up is supported for action templates.